# Terminating while loops at anypoint within the loop by user input, using python

Tags: python, function, while-loop, nested, terminate

I want the user to be able to terminate a nested loop by entering stop or some other keyboard input. The user is asked to enter an option a to g, followed by 8 if statements, Here is the code I wrote for the first if statement...

```
if option == "a":
    while True:
        try:
            name = input('\nEnter the students name: ')
            cm = input('Coursework mark: ')
            em = input('Exam mark: ')
            student = (name,cm,em)
            database.append(student)
        except :
            break
```

I had the idea of using try and except functions but I'm not sure how or if that would work, please help!

Comment: You are on a good way, just don't `except` blindly, it's bad practice, there are a lot of things that can go wrong in your script and you will never know because you're catching all. Just catch `except KeyboardInterrupt:` and you can stop the loop with `CTRL+C`

Answer (score 2):

You can check the value entered each time and if it matches your keyword (or is in a list of keywords) you `break`.

```
if option == "a":
    while True:
        name = input('\nEnter the students name: ')
        if name == 'stop':
            break
        cm = input('Coursework mark: ')
        if cm == 'stop':
            break
        em = input('Exam mark: ')
        if em == 'stop':
            break
        student = (name,cm,em)
        database.append(student)
```

For checking against a list of stop keywords, you could do something like

```
stop_kws = ['stop', 'exit', 'quit']

...

if name in stop_kws:
    break

...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about keyboard interrupts (such as Ctr + c or Delete), you can use the [built-in Exception KeyboardIntertupt](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt).  This will allow you to fail gracefully:

```
if option == "a":
    try:
        name = input('\nEnter the students name: ')
        cm = input('Coursework mark: ')
        em = input('Exam mark: ')
        student = (name,cm,em)
        database.append(student)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        #
        # do something 
        #
        break
```

This would prevent your loop from crashing from interrupt requests.